# Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits

Today in my analysis class, we were preparing for the final and this question came up:

> Evaluate $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}$$

We tried taking the $\log$, using L'Hopitals and some other tricks but couldn't figure it out.

I thought maybe viewing this limits as a sequence in the following way might help;

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{e^{-n^2}}{1/n} = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\frac{n}{e^{n^2}}$$

But from them I'm not sure.

Thank you.

Comment: You can get $\lim$ (instead of $lim$) with `\lim`.

Comment: Thanks @BrianM.Scott   ! Learn something new everyday!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Git Gud’s comment (now deleted) is right, but you have to be a little careful when you change the variable. You have

$$\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}=\lim_{x\to 0}\frac1{xe^{1/x^2}}\;,$$

and you’d like to substitute $u=\frac1x$ and take the limit as $u\to\infty$. However, $u\to\infty$ only if $x\to 0^+$; if $x\to 0^-$, then $u\to-\infty$, so I do two calculations:

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac1{xe^{1/x^2}}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{u}{e^{u^2}}\overset{*}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac1{2ue^{u^2}}=0\;,$$

and

$$\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac1{xe^{1/x^2}}=\lim_{-u\to\infty}\frac{-u}{e^{u^2}}\overset{*}=\lim_{u\to\infty}\frac{-1}{2ue^{u^2}}=0\;.$$

(In each calculation the starred equality is from l’Hospital’s rule, though you should recognize without it that $-$ as Git Gud said $-$ the exponential in the denominator **crushes** the numerator.) Since the two one-sided limits are equal, the original limit is also $0$.

Comment: :) Thanks for the reference, alas I deleted the comment before you answered.

Comment: @GitGud: Oh, well. (I liked it.)

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: thanks. Can these two limits be different? In such case does it mean that the limit does not exist?

Comment: @Alex: Yes, they can, though I might have to use a two-part definition to cook up a function illustrating that behavior. And yes, in that case the original limit would not exist.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott: great, thanks again.

Comment: @Alex: You’re welcome.

Comment: Really no need for such an extended calculation of two one-sided limits. Simply notice that this function $f$ satisfies $|f(x)|=f(|x|)$ and apply the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @AnneBauval: Yes, that will work for this particular function. But pædagogically it is more important that a student understand how to deal with the general case. And in this case doing so proved valuable, as you can see from the OP’s comments under my answer.

Answer (score 9):

We can write
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{x}{e^{x^2}}
$$
and then use de l'Hospital to obtain
$$
\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x} = \lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{1}{2xe^{x^2}} = 0.
$$

Comment: Not without more attention to detail: $\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{x}{e^{x^2}}=\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}x$, not the original two-sided limit.

Comment: (+1) Best answer imo. Alternatively: [Compute $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}$ without using L'Hopital?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2168549/compute-lim-x-to-0-frace-1-x2x-without-using-lhopital).

Comment: @AnneBauval: Since it’s not entirely correct as it stands, and another answer is, it is clearly not the best answer.

Comment: I said "imo", and I explained why in my comment to your answer. I saw your reply and I don't agree ([parsimony](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor) is a good thing to teach, as opposed to wordiness) but it would be useless to argue more.

Comment: @xen As shown by the first comment above, your $\lim_{x\to\infty}$ can be wrongly interpreted as $\lim_{x\to+\infty}.$ To avoid ambiguity, better write $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}.$

Answer (score 3):

As you noted, it sufficed to compute $\displaystyle \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{e^{n^{2}}}$. Well, using L'Hopital and the squeeze theorem and whatnot,

$$
0 \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{e^{n^{2}}} \leq \lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n}{e^{n}} = \lim \frac{1}{e^{n}} = 0.
$$