# Find the second Taylor polynomial of $f(x,y)= \exp\left( -\frac {1}{x^2+y^2}\right)$ near (0,0)

Tags: multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

I want to find the second degree Taylor polynomial of
\begin{equation}
f=
             \begin{cases}
             \exp\left({\frac{-1}{x^2+y^2}}\right), & (x,y)\neq(0,0)  \\
             0, & (x,y)=(0,0)
             \end{cases}
\end{equation}
I know the first step is to calculate the first partial derivatives at $0.$
However, $\dfrac{e^{-1/h^2}}{h}\to\infty$ as $h \to 0$
and I don't know how to proceed.

Comment: The derivative goes to infinity, or goes to 0?  I think that all of the partials will be zero.  You cannot build a Taylor series centered at 0 for this function.

Comment: Does the exercise ask you to do this, or are you trying to do this to achieve something else?

Comment: exercise asked me to find the second degree Taylor polynomial

Comment: I’d guess that your polynomial is $0$ — the problem is showing that the derivatives of first and second order exist and are all zero.

Comment: You could always expand about a point other than zero... Or is that a restriction of the problem?

Comment: @DougM You can define the Taylor series just fine, as the function is infinitely differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Maybe https://planetmath.org/infinitelydifferentiablefunctionthatisnotanalytic will clear things up for you, Winnie.

Comment: the problem is to find the expansion around (0,0).
p.s. Can someone show me that the function is differentiable at zero?

Comment: Did you look at the link I gave, Winnie?

Comment: I see. But then what do we take away from the fact that $\dfrac{e^{-1/h^2}}{h}\to\infty$ as $h \to 0$ ?

Comment: The limit is $0$, not $\infty$, Winnie (see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350418/evaluating-lim-limits-x-rightarrow0-frace-1-x2x)). That's what Dong M is trying to tell you.

Comment: Making any progress, Winnie?

Comment: I understand now. So we have $f_x(0,0)= f_y(0,0)=0$. If we proceed, we'll find that the second partials at $(0,0)$ are also zero.
So the second degree Taylor polynomial at (0,0) is 0. Am I right?

Comment: Looks right to me.