# Derivative of the piecewise function: $\{e^{-1/x^2}\text{ for } x ≠ 0, 0\text{ for }x = 0\}$

Tags: limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

I know that one must use the right- and left-hand limit definition of a derivative to calculate $f'(0)$ for the function

$$f(x) = \begin{cases} 
e^{-1/{x^2}} & \text{if } x≠0\\ 
0 & \text{if } x = 0 \end{cases}$$

since we cannot be sure that $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x = 0$. However, when trying to evaluate this derivative limit expression, I encountered a problem:

$$f'(0) = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac{f(x+h) - f(h)}{h} = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac {e^{-1/h^2}-0}h = \lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac {e^{-1/h^2}}{h}$$

There does not seem to be a way to evaluate the limit $$\lim_{h \to 0^+} \frac {e^{-1/h^2}}{h}$$
without running into an indeterminate form. One could set up a table of values to calculate it and the left-hand version, which would reveal that they both approach $0$ (so $f'(0)$ is then $0$). However, I was curious if this is the only path to take? Is there a way to algebraically calculate this limit? I tried applying L'hospital's rule as well, but that also just ended up resulting in an indeterminate form.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Evaluating $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{e^{-1/x^2}}{x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/350427/386889)